# How do I create a shallow render of my component using Enzyme and Jest?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to follow the documentation for creating a shallow render with Enzyme and Jest to the best of my ability, but I seem to be missing something.  Here is my component.

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      code: ""
    }
  }

  getCode() {
    return "7";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

When I call getCode() on my shallow render, I expect to get "7", but the render is undefined.

Here is my test case:

```
import Example from './Example'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

it('gets a code from example', () => {
  const component = shallow(<Example />);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(component));

  expect(component.getCode().toEqual('7'));
});
```

And my output:

```
 FAIL  src/components/CreateGame/Example.test.js (8.116s)
  ● Console

    console.log src/components/CreateGame/Example.test.js:7
      {}

  ● gets a code from example

    TypeError: component.getCode is not a function

       7 |   console.log(JSON.stringify(component));
       8 |
    >  9 |   expect(component.getCode().toEqual('7'));
         |                    ^
      10 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/CreateGame/Example.test.js:9:20)
```

I feel like I'm probably missing something small here, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: What is ```getCode```? Where is it coming from? I suspect it's throwing an error because it doesn't exist.

Comment: ```getCode``` is a function inside my Example component.  It should return "7", but the entire shallow render is just empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getCode` is a method inside your component, you have to get the `instance`:

```
import Example from './Example'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

it('gets a code from example', () => {
  const component = shallow(<Example />);
  const instance = component.instance(); // This is missing

  expect(instance.getCode().toEqual('7'));
});
```

Comment: Solved, thank you!  I knew there was something small

Answer (score 0):

I went through a similar struggle and ultimately this is what I got to work:

```
import { Example } from './example.js'

describe('Test example', () => {
  test('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(shallow(<Example />)).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

This will create a snapshot but you can easily modify that to be what you want to expect.

Note: I'm using jest ^24.9.0, enzyme ^3.10.0, and enzyme-adapter-react-16 ^1.14.0.